# how do I initialize the first column starting with the prefix ABC with pandas in python?

Tags: python

Hello everyone, in a dataframe I would like to retrieve the number of the first column which begins with "ABC" in its name.

Here is what i tried
data [data.columns [pd.Series (data.columns) .str.startswith ('ABC')]]
but this command gives me all the columns that start with this prefix "ABC" and this is not my goal I just want to get the index of the first column starting with 'ABC'.

Best Regards,
Samia

Answer (score 0):

you could use `df.filter` with the regex match, and then extract the column from that:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]], ['r', 'x', 'p'], ['x', 'ABC', 'z'])
>>> df.columns.get_loc(df.filter(regex='^ABC').columns.item())
1
```

the filter will give all columns starting 'ABC' and then using `df.columns.item()` will limit to just the first item in that set.